# How to change value of XML Node with Self closing Tag using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file, which is being loaded into an XmlDocument object in my code. It contains some nodes which have self closing tags. How do I access and change the text contained within these ? I.E. I can access the text of non self closing tags using `node.InnerText` (`<tag>value</tag>`), but that does not work for self closing tags (`<tag valueName = value/>`).

Comment: The concept of "self-closing" doesn't exist in `XmlDocument`. In markup form, it's just a shorter way of representing "this node has no inner text". In the DOM, markup doesn't exist, and inner text is inner text.

Comment: That said, *"does not work"* is too vague. Please post your code and indicate what about it doesn't do what you expected. Define your expectations and show what happens instead.

Comment: Perhaps you want to change the value of `valueName = value` attribute not the `node.text`.

Comment: I may be better to append to end of the xml rather than add to middle.  A well formed XML file has one root element.  You can have an array of elements at root.  Often arrays are used when a xml is used as a log file so you can append to end rather the open and edit in the middle.

Comment: @madreflection Does not work means It returns nothing. Now I see. It is explained by there being no inner text, just attribute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a beginner at C#, I was unaware of the `node.Attributes` property. I can simply access valName using:
`string valName = node.Attributes["valName"].Value;`
This will assign val to valName.